# pymongo get rid of ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I'm using pymongo to insert records into my mongodb database:

```
mongo = MongoClient('localhost',3001)
db = mongo.meteor
db.clients.insert({"hi":"test"})
```

the id of the inserted record is of type:

> _id: ObjectId("57e92af647700265a2427f69")

is it possible to insert a record and generate an id as a string only without the Objectid?

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify the `_id` on insert:

```
db.clients.insert({"hi":"test", "_id":"123"})
```